# Android - Manufacturer specific battery saving

Tags: android, save, battery

Im developing a chat app which uses GCM to notify the user of incoming messages. One problem I can't seem to fix is that every manufacturer seems to implement his own battery saving in addition to the doze feature of Android. Most of the time a few apps get automatically put on the whitelist of these phones(like whatsapp).

As example Huawei uses "Protected Apps" and only if the user accepts my Intent which tries to add my App to the protected apps, only then my app works as expected.

Is there any way to get whitelisted or something like that for every manufacturer ? I can't believe I have to buy every phone on the market to test if somebody decided the doze feature is not enough.

Best Regards!

Comment: First why using GCM instead of the new FCM ?? Because in FCM you can set priority of the message and send a message when the phone is not sleeping or has a lot of charge. Also why are you afraid being blacklisted if your app is worth it users will always use it.

Comment: Because every app is automatically blacklisted, except for a few ones which is decided by the manufacturer and most users even have no idea about this "feature"